# UTF-8 not working on VIM

Tags: microsoft-windows, encoding

I've searched a lot about this on Internet but nothing's working.

I'm using Vim 8.0.3 on Windows 10 and I can't get the right encoding to work. It's not a problem when writing code, but the problem comes when I try to write some text, mostly because I normally use Spanish and some characters are changed for other symbols. Here's an screenshot:

[image]

I don't think the problem is because I'm using Cmder, because in CMD and Powershell I have the same problem. Maybe any of you have the solution to this.

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? encoding is it set to utf8  (`set encoding`) ?

Comment: try set encoding=utf-8 in the vimrc file

Answer (score 7):

**GENERAL SETTINGS**

Vim internal use of encoding (this settings is must if you like to use utf-8 or you would like to convert encoding from one to another). I strongly recommend to set this setting in _vimrc file (Windows equivalent of Linux .vimrc file). You can open your _vimrc file with command: :e $MYVIMRC

> :set encoding=utf-8

Bellow is actual setting that will convert to utf-8 when you execute :w  (saving file). You can also set this in _vimrc file.

> :set fileencoding=utf-8

There is also smart to set encodings (notice "s" at the end of command).
Bellow settings tries to recognize the encoding of existing file when file is opened. I also suggest to save this setting in _vimrc file.

> :set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf8,latin1

**SAMPLE HOW TO CONVERT FILE ENCODING FROM ONE ENCODING TO ANOTHER**

Now lets say you have a file in some other encoding like cp1250 (latin2) and you would like to convert encoding to utf-8.

1. Set internal Vim encoding to utf-8. A must have setting if multiple code pages are used and converting between them.

   > :set encoding=utf-8
2. Open file and let Vim know what is your current encoding file is saved in (e.g. cp1250 for Eastern Europe encodings = latin2)

   > :e ++enc=cp1250 YourFile.txt

or if file already opened: :e! ++enc=cp1250

3. Set target file encoding to utf-8:

   > :set fileencoding=utf-8
4. Now do actual save (conversion happens now):

> :w

Answer (score 3):

Windows doesn't use UTF-8 natively. [It uses UTF-16LE by default](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#UTF-16LE). If you do not [change the Windows console to UTF-8](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8), it is not going to do what you want with the text.

Part of the problem may be that you aren't using [Windows console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_console), at least not directly: your screenshot shows you're using a third-party tool called [Cmder](http://cmder.net/), which may be part of the problem. It is possible that the UTF-8 solution linked above will fix Cmder, too, but if not, try running Vim via `cmd.exe` instead.

If that fixes it, you might want to switch to the [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) build of Vim, since Cygwin normally uses [MinTTY](https://mintty.github.io/), a considerably nicer console program than the stock Windows one. Because Cygwin is trying to emulate Linux atop Windows, it uses UTF-8 by default.